# java objects, shared variables

Tags: java, static-members

I have a simple question here.
If I declare a variable inside an object which was made [declared] in the main class, like this:

```
public static int number;
```

(
usually I declare it like this **:**

```
private int number;
```

)

can it be used in a different object which was also made [declared] in the main class?
btw I do not care about security atm, I just want to make something work, don't care about protection)

Comment: I'd like to help.  Can you clear up the way you're declaring the "number" variable within your main loop?  I can't tell if you're making `public static int` part of the class that's declared in "main" or if you're declaring `private int` in the class declared in "main."

Comment: You may not care about security at the moment, but do you care about proper learning of Java and OOP concept for long term future? Because now would be a good opportunity to start.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a telling quote from Java Language Specification:

#### [JLS 8.3.1.1 `static` Fields](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.3.1.1)

> If a field is declared `static`, there exists exactly one incarnation of the field, no matter how many instances (possibly zero) of the class may eventually be created. A `static` field, sometimes called a *class variable*, is incarnated when the class is initialized.
>
> A field that is not declared `static` (sometimes called a non-`static` field) is called an *instance variable*. Whenever a new instance of a class is created, a new variable associated with that instance is created for every instance variable declared in that class or any of its superclasses.
>
> *[Example program follows...]*

In short, a `static` field is a *class* variable: it belongs to the class, as opposed to the *instances* of the class. In a way, you can think of a  `static` field as a variable shared by instances of the class, but it's much more consistent to think of `static` fields as belonging to the class, just like `static` method also belongs to the class, etc.

Since they belong to the class, they do not require an instance of said class to access (assuming adequate visibility), and in fact it's considered bad programming practice to access `static` members through an instance instead of a type expression.

#### Related questions

- [Java - static methods best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538870/java-static-methods-best-practices)
- [Static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658407/static-methods)
- [calling non-static method in static method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042813/calling-non-static-method-in-static-method-in-java)
- [non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context (java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559527/non-static-variable-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context-java)
- [When NOT to use the static keyword in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766715/when-not-to-use-the-static-keyword-in-java)
- [Static variables and methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606196/static-variables-and-methods)

Answer (score 0):

`static` variables are shared by all instances of a given class. If it's `public`, it is visible to everything.
non-static variables belong to only one instance.

Since your `main` method is `static`, it can only see `static` variables. But you should avoid working statically - make an instance of a class, and pass the data around as method/constructor parameters, rather than sharing it via `static` variables.

Comment: To be clear, it can only see static *fields* - variables declared inside the body of a class but not inside a method. That confused me a LOT in the first couple weeks.

Comment: Also, different idea so different comment: Working statically is pretty much the same thing as working with global variables and methods. It's the antithesis of OOP, but it's not always a bad thing... yes, Java *is* my primary language.

Comment: yes, `fields` = `instance variables`. But since there are no other `static` variables, I think it's ok to call them this way.

Answer (score 0):

If the class holding 'number'  is called MyClass
you can refer to it as MyClass.number from any method.

Doing so for a variable is not good design though.

Answer (score 0):

There are really two issues here: public vs. private in the context of inner classes, and static variables.

**Part 1:**

*static* means that you don't need an *instance* of the class to access that variable. Suppose you have some code like:

```
class MyClass {
 public static String message = "Hello, World!";
}
```

You can access the property this way:

```
System.out.println(MyClass.message);
```

If you remove the *static* keyword, you would instead do:

```
System.out.println(new MyClass().message);
```

You are accessing the property in the context of an *instance*, which is a copy of the class created by the *new* keyword.

**Part 2:**

If you define two classes in the same java file, one of them must be an *inner class*. An inner class can have a *static* keyword, just like a property. If *static*, it can be used separately. If not-static, it can only be used in the context of a class instance.

Ex:

```
class MyClass {
 public static class InnerClass {
 }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
new MyClass.InnerClass();
```

Without the 'static', you would need:

```
new MyClass().new InnerClass(); //I think
```

If an inner class is *static*, it can only access *static* properties from the outer class. If the inner class is non-static, it can access any property. An inner class doesn't respect the rules of *public*, *protected*, or *private*. So the following is legal:

```
class MyClass {
 private String message;

 private class InnerClass {
  public InnerClass() {
   System.out.println(message);
  }
 }
}
```

If the inner class has keyword *static*, this would not work, since *message* is not static.